# Java passing subclass instance data to superclass constructors

Tags: java, polymorphism, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

Does anybody know if there's a way in Java to set the value of an instance variable in a subclass before calling the superclass constructor. I have a brief schematic below of what I'm trying to accomplish -- I need to set up the instance variables defined in the superclass differently depending on the subclass type, but I still want to be able to share common non-constructor code among different instances of the subclass.

Is there any clean way to do this, maybe some sort of coding pattern that I'm missing or something? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

```
public abstract class ConstraintSatisfactionProblem {

    final Set<Variable> variables;
    final Set<Constraint> constraints;

    public Foo() {
        this.variables = setupVariables();
        this.constraints = setupConstraints();
    }

    public abstract Set<Variable> setupVariables();

    public abstract Set<Constraint> setupConstraints();

    public Map<Variable, Constraint> solve() { ... }
}

public class WordSquare extends ConstraintSatisfactionProblem {

    final int size;
    final static Set<Character> domain = ...;

    public WordSquare() {
        super();         // can I simulate calling super() after setting this.value = 4?
        this.value = 4;
    }

    public Set<Variable> setupVariables() {
        this.variables = new HashSet<Variable>();
        for(int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
            for(int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
               variables.add(new Variable<Pair, Character>(new Pair(row, col), domain);
            }
        }
        return this.variables;
    }

    public Set<Constraint> setupConstraints() {
        // setup code specific to this problem
    }
}

public class Cryptarithmetic extends ConstraintSatisfactionProblem {

    final String problem;

    public Cryptarithmetic(String problem) {
        super();
        this.problem = problem;
    }

    public Set<Variable> setupVariables() {
        this.variables = new HashSet<Variable>();
        for(char c : problem.toCharArray()) {
            variables.add(new Variable<Character, Integer>(c, getDomain());
            }
        } 
        return this.variables;
    }

    public Set<Constraint> setupConstraints() {
        // setup code specific to this problem
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the coding pattern is called `Don't do it` - you're violating one of the most basic safety guarantees for OOP here: Never call a non-final method from a constructor. Yes there are some extremely, extremely rare situations where some people tell me it makes sense (Jon does it in Noda time iirc), but I haven't come across one where overhauling the object hierarchy wasn't the right thing to do in such a situation.

Comment: Perhaps explore Abstract Factory or Builder to construct the object in a valid state rather than having the base invoke a virtual method in the constructor. I'm sure there are questions that already exist on the patterns.

Comment: So would it be okay if I changed the signature of `WordSquare.setupVariables` (and the similar methods) to `public final Set<Variable> setupVariables()`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please don't.

Secondly, really it's a really bad idea. Don't. Think about what you are trying to do in a broader context.

If you absolutely must do, you can stash it in a `ThreadLocal`. You can call a (non-instance) method by evaluating an expression the result of which is passed to a `super()` or `this()` (possibly the only reason why you need a second, private constructor that possibly takes a `Void` (capital 'V') argument). It's so evil, I am not going to even write the code down.

In your edited example code, just pass the sets into a protected constructor. If you have many arguments possibly some subclasses being special about some arguments, you might want to wrap all the arguments into a single argument object.

There is another really hacky approach, so long as you have `-target 1.4` or later (which you should do!). Make the subclass an inner class (possibly anonymous). The references to the outer this and other captured variables are available before calling the super constructor.

```
public class Outer {
    // What a hack!
    private static abstract class Base {
        Base() {
            hello(); // Calling a virtual method in a constructor - poor form.
        }
        abstract void hello();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do not do this.
        final String hi = "Hi!";
        new Base() {
            void hello() {
                // Really, don't do it.
                System.err.println(hi);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Well only if he stores the value before calling the constructor - there's no way to execute another instance method before the super call after all. Edit: Ok after your edit, yep that would work - static method that returns something the parent constructor accepts.. goodness

Comment: I'm trying to write nice, clean code, so I won't do it. But what do you suggest is the best way to handle this situation. I can't be the first person who needed to pass subclass-specific instance data to a subclass-specific instance method through a superclass constructor...

Comment: @jay the simplest solution would be some factory pattern that calls the setup method afterwards. Although without more context it's not clear why you have to call the non-final method in your parent's constructor in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Place the common code you want to run in a protected method instead of in the constructor. Call that method when you wish.

Comment: But then I can't require all subclasses to call the `setup()` method, so I have no way of guaranteeing that my Bar is set up correctly. Or is that just how things need to be with Java?

Comment: There's no way around Java's restriction, so I guess you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if you want to call a base class's constructor, you have to do it on the first line of your sub-class's constructor. So the answer is no, you can't set `this.value` before calling the super class's constructor.

But your sub-class's `setup()` method is already called in the super's constructor. Why don't you set your value there?

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I didn't pay attention that your 'setup()' method returns a value. What you could do is make an abstract `init()` method in your super class, and call it in your super constructor before you call the `setup()` method. This way sub-classes will be forced to implement `init()`, and you would know that that is the place to initialize any sub-class's members before they are used in your super-class.

That being said, this approach does not force safety on you. When you call the super constructor from your sub-constructor, the sub-class instance is just starting to get created. It still needs to run the rest of the code in the sub-constructor before the object is safely created.

And in this situation, the super-constructor goes and calls the `init()` method on your just-in-the-process-of-creation sub-class. This means that if you go with approach, you have to be extra careful about what you do in the `init()` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call any "alien" method (ie. overridable method of this class, or any method from any other class) form within a constructor. As long as the object is not fully initialized, you may have side-effects like the one you see.

In your case, in the subclass constructor, super() is called even before the "value" is set to 4. This means, the superclass constructor is called, then calls the "setup" method, while the "value" is still at 0.

Only once the superclass constructor returns, the "value" is set to 4. And it's too late then.

What I would recommend, is to set the "o1" variable to protected, so that subclasses can set its value themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, don't do this. If you want to share some code between these classes, try containment/encapsulation instead of inheritance.

```
public class Foo {

    private final Object o1;

    public Foo(Object o) {
        o1 = o;
    }

    public void complexMethodCommonToAllSubclassesOfFoo() { ... }
    }

public class Bar {

    private final int value;
    private final Foo foo;

    public Bar() {
        super(); 
        this.value = 4;
        this.foo = new Foo( new Object() ); // or whatever
    }

    // If you need to expose complexMethodCommonToAllSubclassesOfFoo to clients of this class, just add the method and delegate to foo like this
    public void complexMethodCommonToAllSubclassesOfFoo() {
        foo.complexMethodCommonToAllSubclassesOfFoo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set up the instance variables defined in the superclass differently depending on the subclass type, but I still want to be able to share common non-constructor code among different instances of the subclass.

In that case, create a protected constructor in the superclass, and pass all of the customized values to it when you construct the subclass.